# How to add mapping to a form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form which I create using a form class. One field of this form is country_id, which gives me a country id in a text field.

However, I want create a select field instead, and not only with all ids, but rather with country names mapped by those ids.

I have a table in a database mapping country ids to names. However, the form uses only one entity, not this one.

How can I create that select using this other table here? How can I solve this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', ['required' => false])
            ->add('address', 'text', ['required' => false])
            ->add('zipCode', 'text', ['required' => false])
            ->add('city', 'text', ['required' => false]);

        $builder->add('country', 'entity', [
            'class'    => 'AcmeBundle:Country',
            'property' => 'shortName',
            'required' => false,
        ]);

        // $builder->add('country', 'text', ['required' => false]);

        $builder->add('number', 'text', ['required' => false]);
    }
```

That's the whole method inside the, let's call it, Foo entity. It generates proper HTML with ids as values, but there are still those errors I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: You've added your FormType not your Entity. Please add that aswell.

Comment: entity was created from the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `entity Field Type`. Your `FormType` should look like this:

```
$builder->add('country', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'YourBundle:Country',
    'property' => 'name',
));
```

[Checkout the docs for more info.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: Great! But how can I map these names to id, so that I can insert it to the entity in a basic form?

Comment: Thats what the `'property' => 'name'` is for. It makes sure the name of the country is displayed but the ID will be stored in the database

Comment: True, and all values are correct, but I get "object of Contry entity type cannot be converted to int". Why is that so?

Comment: Please add your code to your question so I can have a closer look

Comment: Ok, sure, I just pasted entity class, anything else?